# Output of stats::anova() in R when comparing glm vs glmer

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I'm looking to compare two models,

```
a0 <- glm(dv ~ IV1 + IV2, family=binomial, data=data) 
a  <- glmer(dv ~ IV1 + IV2 + (1|ID), family=binomial, data=data)
```

I compared them using analysis of deviance:

```
stats::anova(a0, a, test="chisq")
```

and the output lists the variables used in both models and gave me significance value for each variable. It seems that when stats::anova() used to compare glm vs glmer, it'll give me the results on whether the relationship between each independent variable and dependent variable differs across the items/clusters in the random effects, is this correct?

Comment: Can you show the output, of summary(a), summary(a0) and the anova()?

Comment: To ensure correct method dispatch, the mixed-effects model should always be the first argument: `anova(a, a0)`